# Why is triangle rendering background color over image?

Tags: c#, .net, opengl, opentk

I am displaying a bitmap
[image]
from png at 800x600 yet when rendered:
[image: image with unwanted triangle]

I have a Window class that inherits GameWindow and here are the overridden methods that (I believe) are relevant:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);

    GrafxUtils.InitTexturing();
    textureId = GrafxUtils.CreateTextureFromBitmap((Bitmap)currentImage);

    OnResize(null);
    GL.ClearColor(Color.Gray);

}

protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e) {
    base.OnRenderFrame(e);

    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Texture);
    GL.LoadIdentity();
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, textureId);
    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);

    //  top-left
    GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
    GL.Vertex2(0, 0);

    //  top-right
    GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
    GL.Vertex2(currentImage.Width, 0);

    //  bottom-left
    GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
    GL.Vertex2(0, currentImage.Height);

    //  bottom-right
    GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
    GL.Vertex2(currentImage.Width, currentImage.Height);

    GL.End();

    SwapBuffers();
}
```

... and the CreateTextureFromBitmap method:

```
// utility method from GrafxUtils
public static int CreateTextureFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(
      new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
      ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
      System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var tex = GetBoundTexture();
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, tex);
    GL.TexImage2D(
      TextureTarget.Texture2D,
      0,
      PixelInternalFormat.Rgba,
      data.Width, data.Height,
      0,
      OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra,
      PixelType.UnsignedByte,
      data.Scan0);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
    SetParameters();
    return tex;
}
```

What would be causing the triangle to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage of currentImage.Width/ currentImage.Height for vertex coordinates is not correct. It should have a range from -1 to 1. In your case, since you seem to be drawing from 0 to 1 (ie, quarter of the screen only), the top left should be (0,0) top right should have (1,0) and bottomleft should have (0,-1), bottomright should have (1,-1). If you instead wanted full screen quad, it should range from -1,-1 to 1,1.

As for the strange shape you are observing, you are drawing 2 triangles, but winding order not taken care of. ie, one triangle whose hypotenuse is from top left to bottom right, and another triangle whose hypotenuse is from bottom left to top right. Hence the shape. You can see for example,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464051.aspx

And also,

[Index Buffer Object and UV Coordinates don't play nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074552/index-buffer-object-and-uv-coordinates-dont-play-nice/21076233#21076233)

Comment: I am not intentionally drawing any triangles. :) ... what is the winding order?

Comment: I looked at the XNA link ... What is the relevance? Is there an order in which I am supposed to set the TexCoord2 and Vertex2??? That's all I'm getting out of this. :)

Comment: Okay ... you helped me get in the direction I needed. Although not a complete answer, I'm giving +1. :) I will most likely post an answer after I have completed a scaling function.